# SQL Server Agent does not allow to set parameters for a SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My SQL Server version is 2012.

I have an SSIS package that is registered in a SQL Server. I have created a SQL Server Agent Job to run my SSIS package.

The SSIS has parameters. So, I thought that a parameter may be set in SQL Server Agent Job GUI:

```
SQL Management Studio 
    -> SQL Server Agent 
       -> Jobs 
          -> My Job 
             -> Job Set properties 
                -> configuration.
```

I see that a Parameters tab does exist, but it is disabled and displays nothing, whereas my SSIS has several parameters:

[image]

How can this problem be fixed?

Comment: Not enough permissions. Please ask to add your AD account to the **ssis_admin** role in the SSISDB database.

Comment: What does the Package tab show for the SQL Agent Job Step - Can you please add that to your question?